# pd.to_datetime doesn't work on values similar to '10/30/2022 7:00:00 AM +01:00'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format, strftime

I have a pandas dataframe with the following column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['10/30/2022 7:00:00 AM +01:00', '10/31/2022 12:00:00 AM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 3:00:00 PM +01:00', '10/30/2022 9:00:00 PM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 5:00:00 PM +01:00', '10/30/2022 10:00:00 PM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 3:00:00 AM +01:00', '10/30/2022 2:00:00 AM +02:00',
       '10/30/2022 10:00:00 AM +01:00', '10/30/2022 4:00:00 PM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 1:00:00 AM +02:00'], columns = ['Date'])
```

I want to convert the date values so it looks like the following:

> 2022-10-30T00:00:00+02:00

I tried the following;     `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`

The code raises an error whenever the `.dt` is called:

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Apparently the code `pd.to_datetime()` does not work.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# convert to date 
# convert to your format
df['Date']=df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

```
0     2022-10-30T07:00:00+0100
1     2022-10-31T00:00:00+0100
2     2022-10-30T15:00:00+0100
3     2022-10-30T21:00:00+0100
4     2022-10-30T17:00:00+0100
5     2022-10-30T22:00:00+0100
6     2022-10-30T03:00:00+0100
7     2022-10-30T02:00:00+0200
8     2022-10-30T10:00:00+0100
9     2022-10-30T16:00:00+0100
10    2022-10-30T01:00:00+0200
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: This does not match the desired output: 2022-10-30T00:00:00+02:00

Answer (score 2):

Add `utc=True` when converting to datetime. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['10/30/2022 7:00:00 AM +01:00', '10/31/2022 12:00:00 AM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 3:00:00 PM +01:00', '10/30/2022 9:00:00 PM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 5:00:00 PM +01:00', '10/30/2022 10:00:00 PM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 3:00:00 AM +01:00', '10/30/2022 2:00:00 AM +02:00',
       '10/30/2022 10:00:00 AM +01:00', '10/30/2022 4:00:00 PM +01:00',
       '10/30/2022 1:00:00 AM +02:00'], columns = ['Date'])

df['Date'] =df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=True)
print(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
0     2022-10-30T06:00:00
1     2022-10-30T23:00:00
2     2022-10-30T14:00:00
3     2022-10-30T20:00:00
4     2022-10-30T16:00:00
5     2022-10-30T21:00:00
6     2022-10-30T02:00:00
7     2022-10-30T00:00:00
8     2022-10-30T09:00:00
9     2022-10-30T15:00:00
10    2022-10-29T23:00:00
```